# WLAN & Debian based Linux distros: Soft-enable WLan by default

Tags: linux-mint, boot, wifi, network-interface

It *seems* Debian based Linux's have **wlan soft-blocked by default**.

I verify it on my Linux Mint laptop: even if you `rfkill unblock all` interfaces (in `rc.local` or in a service...): 2 seconds after boot ends, the **wlan** is softblocked.

How is it possible to not block it, is there settings somewhere ? (*I repeat: `rc.local` or `init.d` service is useless in it)

**NotaBene** By many tests and logs, Im sure `rc.local` commands are executed.

**Note** One of my /etc/init.d/services use `sudo nmcli nm wifi off` to manage a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

you're probably running some tool (e.g., network-manager) which wants to take ownership of your network interfaces and changes the settings.

You essentially have two options:

- Uninstall that tool
- Configure that tool so it doesn't fiddle with your wireless settings.

If it is indeed network-manager, and you want to use that for your wireless settings, then ignore the fact that it's `rfkill`ing your wlan interfaces; it will enable them when you ask it to enable your wireless network.

Comment: @WouterVerheist Thank you. Instinctively I feel network-manager is the thing. Let me investigate... You say:"it will enable them when you ask it to enable your wireless network." This is it: I aim to make a wifi hotspot, which runs from boot, I cannot ignore the NM rf killing.

Comment: I guess that means you don't want to use network-manager, so just remove it: `apt-get remove network-manager`.

Comment: That should be the way, but I need NM for eth0. I have to exclude wlan from NM management.

Comment: No you don't. Install ifupdown for eth0 and get rid of NM.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running Debian 11, and my wifi driver had an rfkill switch that would trigger on boot. Anytime I rebooted, I had to re-enable the wifi adapter. I don't know if it's a bug or if the developers did that intentionally, but as a work-around you can:

1. Go to *Startup Applications > Add > Command*.
2. Write `nmcli radio wifi on`.
3. Name it something like *Wifi Enable on Boot* and click Add.
4. Reboot and your wifi should be enabled.

It's more of a bandaid than a perfect fix, but please consider an up-vote if you found this is helpful.